# Vertically aligned subscript and superscript using NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, subscript, superscript

I have used `NSMutableAttributedString` to generate subscripts and superscripts for strings for a UILabel. I need to generate a subscript and a superscript that are vertically aligned, but when I try, the superscript advances to the next character.

```
// Base String
let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "A")

// Subscript String
let subscriptString = NSAttributedString(string: "1", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset: -1])
string.append(subscriptString)

// Superscript String
let superscriptString = NSAttributedString(string: "2", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset: 5])
string.append(superscriptString)

// Set Label Text
label.attributedText = string
```

Is there a way to make them be vertically aligned?

Comment: What is a "character column"? Do you mean the text wraps?

Comment: Sorry, probably character column isn't the proper term. I want to have the subscript and superscript be vertically aligned. I will edit my question. Thanks

Comment: Maybe playing with the kerning, but else, there shouldn't be anything available in "`NSAttributedString`" at a high level without having to play with CoreText.